# Matplotlib Xticks is not accustomed to string values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe where one column called 'Creation_month' has the numbers of the months in a year. I have the following code running :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 
'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
indexes = []
for i in tickets['Creation_month']:
  indexes.append(i)
index = list(sorted(set(indexes)))

new = tickets.groupby('Creation_month')['number_replies'].sum()
newplot = new.plot.bar()
plt.xticks(index, months)
plt.show()
```

I have the following plot. I do not know how this happens.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not have your data to replicate your problem. Most likely an index problem, with a constructed index starting from one, while Python starts from zero.

Comment: I figured it out myself. Yes, it indeed was an indexing issue. Adding the below lines worked : ax.set_xticks(range(len(new)))
ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation='vertical', ha='center')

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok, I am a new member and did not know about these rules. I will try to refrain from adding these phrases from now on. Thanks for pointing it out